# Apostille document for from non-apostille countries

Tags: legal, residence-cards, indonesia

I am an indonesian marrying a Mauritian. The marriage will take place in Mauritius. To obtain my residence permit, they are asking for:

> Full Birth Certificate of applicant duly legalized/authenticated by
>   competent authority/ bear the seal of  "Apostille" of the Hague
>   Convention of 5th October 1961 (where applicable).

Indonesia is not part of the `Apostille Convention`, I'm in Indonesia, how and where can I legalize my birth certificate by an authority ?

Comment: Talk to the embassy of Mauritius http://www.consulate-info.com/consulate/8890/Mauritius-in-Jakarta

Answer (score 2):

Documents from non-apostille countries are attested, or confirmed to be legal. In Indonesia, your birth certificate must be legalized by the [Ministry of Justice and Human Rights](http://www.kemenkumham.go.id/) and by the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.kemlu.go.id/en/default.aspx). A subsequent attestation or legalization may be required by Mauritius and, to be certain, you should check with the Mauritian Consulate in Jakarta.